# Excel 2010 - Voice command to select cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, speech-recognition

I am using Windows 8, but I would like to know if the solutions provided are also applicable in Windows 7.

I use Excel 2010. What I want is a way to select a cell in an open excel worksheet, using a single word for a specific cell (having previously edited a command to do this). Is that possbile through Windows' own speech recognition, or with any other usable speech recognition program?